# Postgresql Output column from another table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, relational-database

i'm using **Postgresql**, my question is specifically about querying from **a table that's in another table** and i'm really having trouble with this one. In fact, i'm absolutely mentally blocked. I'll try to define the relations of the tables as much as I can.

I have a table **entry** which is like this:

[image: Entry]

Each of the entries has a group_id; when they are 'advanced' to the next stage, the old entries are marked is_active = false, and a new assignment is done, so C & D are advanced stages of A & B.

I have another table (which acts as a record keeper) , in which the **storage_log_id** refers to, this is the **storage_log** table :

[image: Storage Log]

But then I have another table, to really find out where the entries are actually stored - **storage** table :

[image: Storage]

To define my problem properly. Each entry has a storage_log_id (but some doesn't have yet), and a storage_log has a storage_id to refer to the actual table and find the storage label.

The sql query i'm trying to do should output this one:

[image: Joined Table]

Where The actual storage label is shown instead of the log id.

This is so far what i've done:

```
select e.id, e.group_id, e.name, e.stage, s.label
from operational.entry e, operational.storage_log sl, operational.storage s
where e.storage_log_id = sl.id and sl.storage_id = s.id
```

But this just returns 3 rows, showing only the ones that have the seed_storage_log_id set; I should be able to see even those without logs, and especially the active ones.
adding **e.is_active = true** to the condition makes the results empty. So, yeah i'm stuck.

Need help, Thanks guys!

Comment: I very strongly recommend that you avoid the old-style comma-separated `FROM` list. Use ANSI joins like `operational.entry e INNER JOIN operational.storage_log sl ON (e.storage_log_id = sl.id)`. It's a lot more readable in bigger queries and will save your sanity late.r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JOIN to select from more tables:

Here is the query:

```
SELECT 
   e.id, e.group_id, e.name, e.stage, s.label
FROM
   entry e
LEFT JOIN
   storage_log sl
ON 
   sl.id = e.storage_log_id
LEFT JOIN 
   storage s
ON 
   sl.storage_id = s.id
```

If you wanna show just rows with strict relationship, remove LEFT and use just JOIN it will be show just rows which have relation in other table.

I hope this helps.

Comment: there's a syntax error :  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "e".. pointing to the sl.id = e.storage_log_id

Comment: still have it, it says HINT : There is an entry for table "e", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.

Comment: remove the comma after `entry e,`

Comment: Now is right, i have a bad syntax i leave "," at the end of aliases... sorry my mistake :)

Comment: "column s.storage_id does not exist.. on the last line

Comment: Yes you are right, i fix it. But update your ask and add names to the current tables.